# Shopify Alternate Cart Page

Tags: ajax, shopify, liquid

I am displaying a alternate cart template in shopify using the url /cart/?view=alternate. The only problem is that when the cart is updated by either changing quantity or deleting a product it redirects back to the default cart template.

`<a href="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&quantity=0">`

Is there an alternate way to update the cart/remove product for just this template? Or a simple fix I am not seeing?

Comment: Need to find the JS code that responsible for redirect and sent it alternative template path

Comment: What @OnkarSingh said. or swap the alternate template with the original template.